# Umbraco - Get Node by ID programmatically

Tags: c#, umbraco

Running Umbraco 4x I am creating a helper method in C# that I can recursively call to create child categories of a particular node (category).

The method takes a parentNodeID as a parameter. I need to retrieve the properties of that parent node. I know I can use the static method Node.GetCurrent() but I'm looking for something like Node.GetNodeById(parentNodeID).

I just can't see where this method lives. I know there is the umbraco.library.getNodeXMLbyId method, but does that give me the name property of the node?

Me Umbraco N00b :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can just do

```
var node = new Node(nodeId).
```

Took me a while to find it too!

Comment: Wicked. I knew it had to be something simple like that. Cheer Sam!

Comment: Yes, Umbraco's choice of using constructors to return existing persisted instances is rather odd, and I would say... unusual.

Comment: +1 for both. It helped me. I also needed to add
using umbraco.NodeFactory;

Comment: Remember also to use Document instead, if you need to alter the node (http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/difference-between-node-and-document).

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
umbraco.NodeFactory.Node headerNode = uQuery.GetNode(NodeId);
```

add namespace

```
using umbraco.NodeFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
Document doc = new Document(nodeId)
```

This works the same as `Node` but gets the values straight from the database instead of the XML cache. Use this if you're going to be updating the documents property values.

Comment: But be aware that for front end reading, you should always use the published XML node.

Comment: If you do this in Umbraco 7 you will get the warning - 'umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document' is obsolete: 'Obsolete, Use Umbraco.Core.Models.Content'